# C#.net Winform -Multiple forms show & hide

Tags: forms, window, hide, show

I have take 3 forms in visual studio 2008 with c# .net. In Form1 there are 2 buttons ,If i clicked on 1st button then Form2 will show & at same time i clicked on 2nd button then Form3 will show & already opened Form2 will hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//loop through all open forms
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (f.Name != "Form1") //if it's not Form1
        f.Hide(); //then hide it (or close)
}
//show the form you want (ex: Form3)
new Form3().Show();
```

Comment: sir can u explained all lines ?

Comment: All open forms are stored in Application.OpenForms. We loop all the open forms, one by one. and hide all of them, except Form1. Then, we show the Form3 (or another form you want).